# CSS to Enable Two Images of Different Ratios to Fill Container Width and Be Of Equal Height

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to align two images horizontally such that if one image is oriented in landscape and the other is portrait they will adjust their sizing to be of the same height and fill the width of the container. The images are added dynamically and can be of any ratio.

My current approach entails:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
}
.image {
  flex: 1; 
}
```

```
<div class="container">
   <img class="image" src="dynamic-source">
   <img class="image" src="dynamic-source">
</div>
```

Images to help explain problem, I currently have the following:

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f44WW.jpg)

What I am Trying to Accomplish:

[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzshf.jpg)

Please note that in the 'Goal' Image 1 has increased in height and width, while Image 2 has decreased its height and width while both maintain their ratios.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that this request can be achieved with CSS. Hopefully I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing the property align-items: center with align-items: stretch or just remove the property since the default value of align-items is stretch anyway.

This would stretch your flex items to fill the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Add a fixed height to the `.container`, then modify your `.image` class

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap; 
  height: 500px;
}
.image {
  /* flex: 1;  */
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Problem with this: It doesnt span the whole width automatically..

Answer (score 0):

test your code and got your goal result [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reundo/z2b7uv9f/)

if still does not work add `width: 100%;` to img style.